# netlink and big endian format

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, netlink

I have not found any document/note in the kernel that would mandate to pass `16/32-bit` values in netlink messages towards the kernel in network byte order. So my question is if I have to use `htonl`/`htons` functions when filling up netlink message. Is there such requirement at all?

Comment: Otherwise how can you be sure that the order is BIG endian (or network order)? Those calls are no-op on BIG endian CPUs.

Comment: @0andriy, netlink does not traverse beyond the local host, why would it be necessary to ensure the big endian byte order? I think netlink maintains the host byte order?

Answer (score 0):

according to [this article](https://medium.com/@mdlayher/linux-netlink-and-go-part-1-netlink-4781aaeeaca8) this could be controlled on per-attribute basis

> There are two special flags which may be present in netlink
>   attributes, though I have yet to encounter them in my work.
>
> NLA_F_NESTED: specifies a nested attribute; used as a hint for
>   parsing. Doesn’t always appear to be used, even if nested attributes
>   are present. NLA_F_NET_BYTEORDER: attribute data is stored in network
>   byte order (big endian) instead of host endianness

UPD: looks like native (little) endian does not work well for some cases: I'm getting `errno 4097` trying to pass IPSET CREATE timeout using it. network byte order works fine.